# How can I convert a return statement into something that can be used by Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, return

I am making a GFC (Greatest Common Factor) calculator with GUI, but my current code only works with a `return` statement, and tkinter doesn't accept `return` to fill a textbox widget.

Here is a sample of my code

```py
def gproces():
    Gnumber1 = Entry.get(GE1)
    Gnumber2 = Entry.get(GE2)
    Gnumber1 = int(Gnumber1)
    Gnumber2 = int(Gnumber2)

    if Gnumber1 > Gnumber2:
        Gnumber1, Gnumber2 = Gnumber2, Gnumber1

    for x in range (Gnumber1, 0, -1):
        if Gnumber1 % x == 0 and Gnumber2 % x == 0:
            return x
```

Here is where it's supposed to be used: (To fill GE3)

```py
GE3=Entry(top, bd =5)
GE3.grid(row=3, column=4)
GB=Button(top, text ="Submit", command = gproces).grid(row=4,column=4,)
```

How do I convert a return statement into something that can be used by Tkinter?

Comment: So, instead of `return x`, just do `print(x)` / `break`.  Or store it in another Tkinter box.

Comment: simply doing print(x) gives me the wrong answer. How would I store it in another tkinter box?

Comment: After `print`ing you need to `break` the loop tho.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just insert the result into the text box inside `gprocess()`:

```py
def gproces():
    # better cater invalid input
    try:
        Gnumber1 = int(GE1.get())
        Gnumber2 = int(GE2.get())

        x = min(Gnumber1, Gnumber2)
        for x in range(x, 0, -1):
            if Gnumber1%x == 0 and Gnumber2%x == 0:
                break

        # insert result into text box
        GE3.delete(0, 'end')
        GE3.insert('end', x)
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid number input')
```

Note that there is `math.gcd()` to find the GCF.

Comment: I know that there is math.gcd() but I didnt want to use it because
a) It doesnt work
and b) I wanted to give myself a challenge

Answer (score 1):

Ok so if I understand this correctly you want the result to be displayed in a textbox.

This code should work:

```py
T.delete('1.0', tk.END)  # deletes all previous data
T.insert('1.0', str(x))  # inserts new data
```

Where `T` is your textbox.

If you want to fill the Textbox in a loop you can simply run `T.insert('1.0', str(x))` instead of using `return` at the end of your function, or you can use both `return` and `T.insert`, but don't forget to clear the textbox at the begining of the function with `T.delete`.